How can I rotate captions for rotated side by side images
This is my first time working with LaTeX and I found a problem when trying to put two rotated images side by side, here is the code I'm using and its result (in a generic way, changing the images and captions for 1 and 2 to make it more readable):
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=270, width=0.4\textwidth]{image1}
        \caption{caption1}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=270, width=0.4\textwidth]{image2}
        \caption{caption2}
        \label{fig:figure2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


I want to also rotate the captions for these images, but I don't know how to do it.
I tried with \rotcaption but, when using it, the caption goes through the image instead of being at its side.
Any help will be appreciated.

Welcome! Use the rotating package and e.g. sidewaysfigure to rotate the image and caption (or both images and both captions if appropriate) together. If you need more help, please edit to complete your code so we can compile it and use either draft or standard images such as example-image-a.
